# Get parent div id and apply to elements

Tags: jquery, parent, children, attr

I got this HTML Code:

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery_x"> 
    <p>
        <a href="http://a-dynamic-link.com">image1</a>
        <a href="http://another-dynamic-link-com">image2</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

(x = variable number)

and I need to get the ID from the .gallery div and apply it to the "a" as a rel just like this:

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery_x">
    <p>
        <a rel="gallery_x" href="http://a-dynamic-link.com">image1</a>
        <a rel="gallery_x" href="http://another-dynamic-link-com">image2</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

my (not working) solution so far is:

```
$(".gallery a").parents(".gallery").attr("rel", $(this).attr("id"));
```

I would be glad if someone could help me out.

Thank you.

dee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".gallery").each(function(){
    $("a", this).attr("rel", $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('.gallery a').attr('rel', function() {
    return $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
});​
```

Comment: There is no `this` context in the question

Comment: np, it was a couple of minutes before I realised myself :p